Is there a way to export the timestamp values of measurements in the Total Station?
I am using a total station model HI TARGET HTS-420R. I can export data in formats such as .csv, .dat, .dxf, .txt, .gsi. The data is exported as coordinate point name, x, y and z values (or e, n, z). I want to be able to export the timestamp value of these measurements. When I look at the individual measurements using Total Station, I can see the time the measurement was recorded down to the seconds value; however, I could not find a way to export it. Is there a known way to do this, or is the only way to manually add the timestamp value of each data by looking at it individually in Total Station?
I have exported the measurements in all the formats provided in Total Station and checked whether they contain a timestamp value; however, I could not try any other method due to my limited knowledge.
